# How to get the value of the row number in which the value is found in this code?

Tags: vba

How do I get the range or the row number in which the value is found in the following code?
In the If section, I want the row number instead of going to the value like here in this piece of code

```
With wsSource.Range("A:A") 'searches all of column A
      Set Rng1 = .Find(What:=FindString, _
      After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
      LookIn:=xlValues, _
      LookAt:=xlWhole, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=False)
      If Not Rng1 Is Nothing Then
           Application.Goto Rng1, True 'value found
      Else
           MsgBox "Nothing found" 'value not found
      End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Activate the `Rng1` and then get active cell row like below.

```
With wsSource.Range("A:A") 'searches all of column A
      Set Rng1 = .Find(What:=FindString, _
      After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
      LookIn:=xlValues, _
      LookAt:=xlWhole, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=False)
      If Not Rng1 Is Nothing Then
           'Your code
           Rng1.Activate
           'Get Row number
           MsgBox ActiveCell.Row
           'Get Row value
           MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
      Else
           MsgBox "Nothing found" 'value not found
      End If
End With
```

Comment: Why would you want to activate it? Just get `Rng1.Row`.